# Regular Expression to array with string issue

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Having a little issue with RegEx,
I have the strings

```
AM.name:ASC,AMAdvanced.start:DESC,

AMAdvanced.start:DESC,AM.Genre:Action
```

and need to break them into

```
array(0){

AM.name => ASC,

AMAdvanced.start => DESC
}

and 

array(0){

AMAdvanced.start => DESC,

AM.Genre => Action

}
```

Any help would be fantastic since completely new to regex

Comment: *I have the strings* - where is the bound of strings?

Comment: I've tried all the solutions to no effect, the strings will be sent via JQuery and managed server side (with PHP) and every solution nests them incorrectly, the strings are separate and not processed at the same time, i need the script compatible with both, this is the best output so far Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => AM.name [1] => ASC ) [1] => Array ( [0] => AMAdvanced.start [1] => DESC ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => AMAdvanced.start [1] => DESC ) [1] => Array ( [0] => AM.Genre [1] => Action ) ) )

Comment: does it 4 strings? 2 string? 3 strings (one is empty)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of `regex` here.

Steps:

1. `explode` by comma `,`
2. Loop over exploded `array`
3. `Explode` by colon `:`
4. Push into new `array`

Code:

```
$newArr = array();
foreach (explode(',', trim($str, " ,")) AS $el) {
    $el = explode(':', $el);
    $newArr[$el[0]] = $el[1];
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first split your text with new line character :

```
 var arr = data.split('\n');
```

then loop over your array and use `str.replace` method for your items :

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {

 alert(arr[i].replace(/(\w+):(\w+)/g, '$1=>$2'));

}
```

You can also split the result for each item with `,` :

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {

 var temp=arr[i].replace(/(\w+):(\w+)/g, '$1=>$2');
 alert(temp.split(','));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a single array with the entries

```
<?php
$dir = array();
$strArray = array('AM.name:ASC,AMAdvanced.start:DESC','AMAdvanced.start:DESC,AM.Genre:Action');
foreach ($strArray as $i => $str) {
    $el = explode(',', $str);
    foreach ($el as $e) {
        $dir[$i][] = explode(':',$e);
    }
}
print_r($dir);
```